# NestJS - "SyntaxError: Unexpected token const" while "npm run start:prod"

Tags: node.js, webpack, nestjs

I create my project from NestJS Boilerplate (https://github.com/Vivify-Ideas/nestjs-boilerplate).
When I run "npm run start:prod" the following error message appears:

```
/home/xxxxxxxxxx/dist/config/express.d.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { declare const _default: {
                                                                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token const
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```
    {
   "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "removeComments": true,
      "noLib": false,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "baseUrl": "./src"
   },
   "include": [
      "src/**/*"
   ],
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      // "**/*.spec.ts"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe node version being too old ? Check what command is run on `npm run start:prod` (probably `node` something), and check the used node version (`node -v`).

Comment: The command behind "npm run start:prod" is just "node dist/main.js"
Node version 10.13.0

Comment: How are you handling your orm config?  With ormconfig.js, ormconfig.json, or in the app module?